# Issue with using canvas in React

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

Im trying to be able to draw on canvas, I added console log to each function and event listener, and
all of them run when something changes in useEffect, however I cant draw anything onto my canvas, any help is much appriciated.

```js
const canvasOptions = () => {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Start position of drawing
  const startPosition = (e) => {
    setIsPainting(true);
    drawCanvas(e);
  };

  // Finished position of drawing
  const finishedPosition = () => {
    setIsPainting(false);
    ctx.beginPath();
  };

  const drawCanvas = (e) => {
    if (!isPainting) return;
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log('drawing')
  };

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    startPosition(e);
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    finishedPosition();
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    drawCanvas(e);
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  canvasOptions();
}, [isPainting]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here your problem :

```
  const startPosition = (e) => {
    setIsPainting(true);
    drawCanvas(e);
  };
```

you are firing state update `setIsPainting` and then immediately firing `drawCanvas`  which relay on the painting state. and react update state asynchronously so when `drawCanvas` fire:

```
 const drawCanvas = (e) => {
    if (!isPainting) return;
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log('drawing')
  };
```

`isPainting` will be false so the function will return.

to solve this try adding firing drawCanavs in `useEffect` hook or `componentDidUpdate` for class Component like this :

```
useEffect(()=>{
drawCanvas(startPosition)
,[isPainting]}
```

this effect will fire when `isPainting` state change + you need to add extra state to store startPosition or click event.

edited:
final code :

```
const MyCanavas = ()=>{
canvasRef = useRef();
const [isPainting,setIsPainting] = useState({painting:false,startPostion:null})

 const startPosition = (e) => {
const event = e
    setIsPainting({painting:true,startPostion:event});
  };
  const drawCanvas = (e) => {
    if (!isPainting.painting) return;
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log('drawing')
  };
  // Finished position of drawing
  const finishedPosition = () => {
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    setIsPainting({painting:false,startPostion:null});
    ctx.beginPath();
  };

useEffect(()=>{
const canvas = canvasRef.current
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    startPosition(e);
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    finishedPosition();
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    drawCanvas(e);
  });
return ()=>{
canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown")
canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup")
canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove") // clean up 
}

},[])

useEffect(()=>{
drawCanvas(isPainting.startPosition)
},[isPainting] 

return <Canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
}
```

Comment: Oh that makes complete sense. But canvasOptions function is holding all of them and that function is called in useEffect, so I don't have access to drawCanvas function in useEffect as u suggested. Should i just make a variable for true and false instead of having it stored in state then, or is there a different way of fixing it? Thank you.

Comment: Im using contextApi, so I did add everything you told me and I removed MyCanavas component u made. Now ctx is not defined ever, and if I define it at the top under canvasRef = useRef(); I just get undefined everywhere for my ctx

Comment: sorry forgot about that so just add `ctx` where you needed in `drawCanvas ` and `finishedPosition ` functions. check edited answer thanks.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wildflower-6nls1 , It's not letting me answer a question and add a code block so I pasted my whole file here. Thank you so much for the help, but I still can't get it to work, it's still not drawing anything, I'm so lost.

Comment: your codesandbox not working please post a full working example so i can help you out.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-snow-4bhn8 , Here's the full project, on codesandbox, it kinda works only when u click somewhere on top of canvas, its still not what i need, in my actuall project I cant even see that

Comment: i forked your  code and made a full working example here its  https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-einstein-x4wec?file=/src/Hero.js

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I also managed to fix it in a different way while I was waiting. If ur interested I will link you mine now aswell. My e.clientX value were off and some other stuff, sorry I didn't wanna waste your time. How u did it is insane for me, I'm only around 2 months into react so im pretty bad, so thank you once again, Ill fork this for learning it and future references, and do let me know if u wanna see my example that works now after 4 hours :D Cheers!